# Azure cli get Linux Operating system version

Tags: linux, azure, operating-system, command-line-interface, version

Via the Azure cli I can get the Operating system version for Windows machines (using sku), but this does not work for Linux machines.
When I look at the Linux VM in the portal it shows "Operating System" "Linux (centos 7.9.2009)"
How do I get this detail via CLI? (will accept powershell or resource graph kql also)

I had a browse of resources.azure.com and there does not seem anything obvious to query for.
I've also poked around with Powershell Get-AzVM, and Resource graph kusto query.

Here's how i get the info for Windows

```
az vm list --query '[].{ Name:name, offer:storageProfile.imageReference.offer, publisher:storageProfile.imageReference.publisher, sku:storageProfile.imageReference.sku, version:storageProfile.imageReference.version, os:storageProfile.osDisk.osType}'
```

sample output of that cmd is

```
  {
    "Name": "myLinuxServerName",
    "offer": null,
    "os": "Linux",
    "publisher": null,
    "sku": null,
    "version": null
  },
  {
    "Name": "myWindowsServerName",
    "offer": "WindowsServer",
    "os": "Windows",
    "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
    "sku": "2019-Datacenter",
    "version": "latest"
  },
```

here's what i was doing in KQL

```
resources 
| where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines" and properties.storageProfile.imageReference.offer == "WindowsServer"
| project name,offer=properties.storageProfile.imageReference.offer,sku=properties.storageProfile.imageReference.sku,version=properties.storageProfile.imageReference.version,minorversion=properties.storageProfile.imageReference.exactVersion
```

Comment: I have used the above shared kql query and modified the condition to below able to see both linux and windows vms with their respective publisher and versions as well as shown in [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/lgqXQgR.png)

Comment: resources 
| where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines" and  properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType == "Windows" or properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType=="Linux"
| project name,offer=properties.storageProfile.imageReference.offer,sku=properties.storageProfile.imageReference.sku,publisher=properties.storageProfile.imageReference.publisher,version=properties.storageProfile.imageReference.version,minorversion=properties.storageProfile.imageReference.exactVersion

Comment: We have tested the above shared CLI cmdlet projected the output to table using output property using that we are able to linux version as well as sjhown here https://i.imgur.com/JLeRkdT.png

Comment: Hi, Thanks for looking. This is weird. I ran the exact same cmds from both resource graph explorer and from cli.
The Windows VMs have details listed, but the Linux vms either say null or are just blank respectively.
The one exception I have just noticed is a single Cisco virtual appliance based on Linux which has all the details.
Could OS type or original image used impact it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!
There are a couple of other variables that are populated.
osName=properties.extended.instanceView.osName

```
result=centos
```

osVersion=properties.extended.instanceView.osVersion

```
result=7.9.2009
```

My full command is-

```
resources 
| where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
| project name,offer=properties.storageProfile.imageReference.offer,sku=properties.storageProfile.imageReference.sku,publisher=properties.storageProfile.imageReference.publisher,version=properties.storageProfile.imageReference.version,minorversion=properties.storageProfile.imageReference.exactVersion,osName=properties.extended.instanceView.osName,osVersion=properties.extended.instanceView.osVersion
| order by ['name'] asc
```

The other variables still say "null" for my Linux servers